# Draw pieChart with hole

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have "pie" chart, drawn with UIBezierPath. What i want is, to start draw it with offset, to achieve "hole" inside circle. Now it look like this:

[image]

It create "slices" like that:

```
- (void)drawSliceOfPie:(CGFloat)radius startAngle:(CGFloat)startAngle endAngle:(CGFloat)endAngle fillColor:(UIColor *)fillColor strokeColor:(UIColor *)strokeColor lineWidth:(CGFloat)lineWidth
{

    // Draw text


    //draw arc
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.height / 2, self.bounds.size.width / 2);

    UIBezierPath *arc = [UIBezierPath bezierPath]; //empty path
    [arc setLineWidth:lineWidth];
    [arc moveToPoint:center];
    CGPoint next;
    next.x = center.x + radius * cos(startAngle);
    next.y = center.y + radius * sin(startAngle);
    [arc addLineToPoint:next]; //go one end of arc

    [arc addArcWithCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle clockwise:YES]; //add the arc
    [arc addLineToPoint:center]; //back to center

    // Draw text (new)
    float _x, _y, _nextX, _nextY;
    _nextX =center.x + radius/2 * cos(startAngle);
    _nextY =center.y + radius/2 * sin(startAngle);

    _x =_nextX + radius/2 * cos(endAngle);
    _y =_nextY + radius/2 * sin(endAngle);
    // x - 523, y - 472

    NSString *str = @"123";
    CGPoint halfCenter = CGPointMake(_x, _y);
    [str drawAtPoint:halfCenter withAttributes:nil];
    //

    [fillColor set];
    [arc fill];
    [strokeColor set];
    [arc stroke];
}
```

I simply want to achieve "While hole" inside this (not add an subview above, but draw it with offset). How to achieve that?

Comment: a hole is a fixed piece. What difference does it make to draw or add as subview ?

Comment: Instead of `[arc addLineToPoint:center]; //back to center`, calculate the point from center with correct radius, then draw again a `addArcWithCenter:radius:startAndle:endAngle:`?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri because in future it may have gradient, or shadow, it leads to problems.

Comment: @Larme im sorry im not quite understand how to do that..

Comment: You understand what does `addLineToPoint:` and `addArcWithCenter:radius:startAndle:endAngle:`, no? So, instead of drawing with 3 points, you have to draw with 4 points. Just draw a pie you want on a paper, and calculate and then use the previous methods: It's just 2 lines, and two arcs lines.

Comment: @Larme okay, thank you, i will try to.

Comment: Why don't you use a library like ios Charts?  See the pie chart on this link https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Comment: @CarienvanZyl i use it acutally but i dont have pie i want to (with different slice width like on my screen)

Answer (score 3):

Below is the code drawing Pie-chart with whole using UIBezierPath

SWIFT version: -

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.drawCircle(center: self.view.center, radius: 100, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 0.8), color: UIColor.red)
        self.drawCircle(center: self.view.center, radius: 100, startAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 0.8), endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 0.2), color: UIColor.green)
        self.drawCircle(center: self.view.center, radius: 100, startAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 0.2), endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 0.0), color: UIColor.blue)

            }

    func drawCircle(center: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat, startAngle: CGFloat, endAngle:CGFloat, color: UIColor) {

        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle:endAngle, clockwise: false)

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath

        //change the fill color
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        //you can change the stroke color
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = color.cgColor
        //you can change the line width
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 50.0

        view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

    }
}
```

Objective C version:-

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self drawCircle:self.view.center radius:100 startAngle:0 endAngle:(M_PI * 0.8) color:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self drawCircle:self.view.center radius:100 startAngle:(M_PI * 0.8) endAngle:(M_PI * 0.2) color:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [self drawCircle:self.view.center radius:100 startAngle:(M_PI * 0.2) endAngle:(M_PI * 0.0) color:[UIColor blueColor]];
}


- (void) drawCircle:(CGPoint) center radius:(CGFloat)radius startAngle:(CGFloat)startAngle endAngle:(CGFloat)endAngle color:(UIColor *)color
{
    UIBezierPath *circlePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle clockwise:false];
    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    shapeLayer.path = circlePath.CGPath;

    //change the fill color
    shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    //you can change the stroke color
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [color CGColor];
    //you can change the line width
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 50.0;

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's good, i used this for my projects.

```
 extension CGFloat {
func radians() -> CGFloat {
    let b = CGFloat(M_PI) * (self/180)
    return b
}
}

 extension UIBezierPath {
convenience init(circleSegmentCenter center:CGPoint, radius:CGFloat, startAngle:CGFloat, endAngle:CGFloat)
{
    self.init()
    self.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(center.x, center.y))
    self.addArcWithCenter(center, radius:radius, startAngle:startAngle.radians(), endAngle: endAngle.radians(), clockwise:true)
    self.closePath()
}
}



  func pieChart(pieces:[(UIBezierPath, UIColor)], viewRect:CGRect) -> UIView {
var layers = [CAShapeLayer]()
for p in pieces {
    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    layer.path = p.0.CGPath
    layer.fillColor = p.1.CGColor
    layer.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    layers.append(layer)
}
let view = UIView(frame: viewRect)
for l in layers {

    view.layer.addSublayer(l)


}
return view
 }

 let rectSize = CGRectMake(0,0,400,400)
 let centrePointOfChart =      CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rectSize),CGRectGetMidY(rectSize))
 let radius:CGFloat = 100
 let piePieces = [(UIBezierPath(circleSegmentCenter: centrePointOfChart, radius: radius, startAngle: 250, endAngle: 360),UIColor.brownColor()), (UIBezierPath(circleSegmentCenter: centrePointOfChart, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 200),UIColor.orangeColor()), (UIBezierPath(circleSegmentCenter: centrePointOfChart, radius: radius, startAngle: 200, endAngle: 250),UIColor.lightGrayColor())]
pieChart(piePieces, viewRect: CGRectMake(0,0,400,400))
```

Taken from : http://sketchytech.blogspot.com/2016/02/swift-going-round-in-semicircles-with.html

For more help :
 https://github.com/vitorventurin/PieChartComponent
 https://github.com/andjash/AYPieChart